# How to create a json object dynamically using attributes of html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to create a JSON object entirely from the attributes of HTML elements that share the same class so that the key is say the data attribute and value is the id.

I've tried the code below :

```
$("#searchBtn").click(function() {
  var map = [];
  $(".searchTextField").each(function() {
    var fieldName = $(this).attr('data-field-name')
    map.push({
      $(this).attr('data-field-name'): $(this).val()
    })
    alert(map);
  });
})
```

what I want to achieve is to have some like

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "page" : 5
}
```

but id and page must be dynamic i.e the text id is taken from an tribute of an HTML element

Comment: So the result you want is an array of objects, correct?

Comment: I have created a working example of what I think you are after here: https://jsfiddle.net/ft67g42d/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#searchBtn").click(function () {
    var map = [];

    $(".searchTextField").each(function() {
        var element = {}; 

        element.id = $(this).data('field-name');
        element.page = $(this).val();

        map.push(element);
    });

    alert(map);
});
```

Comment: thank you but what i want is instead of element.id can i have something like element.$(this).val() as the object

Comment: @TapiwaTakaindisa Not sure what you mean. Can you give me an example of exactly what you want the resulting object to look like?

Answer (score 1):

```
var dd = {};
dd.test = 5;
```

or

```
var dd = {};
dd['test'] = 5;
```